# Spectrum features in an atmosphere with temperature inversion

Tags: spectroscopy

Consider an atmosphere with a temperature inversion (cooler on the bottom
and hotter on the top). Imagine the hottest one emit as a blackbody. Would we see any absorption/emission lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the top layer "emit[s] as a blackbody", and assuming we are viewing it from above the atmosphere, then we see a Planck spectrum with no absorption features (by definition).

Anything emitting as a blackbody must be [optically thick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_depth) at all wavelengths, which means no light can pass through it from below.